# Does Islam believe that Jesus will come back to rule as the king of Israel?

Tags: prophet-isa, end-times

Shalom Aleikhem my friends I want to know what Islam says about this question:

Does Islam believe that Yahusua (Isha) an important messenger and messiah (servant) of Allah will come again as the king of Israel and glorify the name of Allah (who alone should be worshipped) forever?

Comment: Short Answer: In Islam, we believe that Jesus will come back to rule the world from Jerusalem and unite the monotheistic believers under one religion (Islam) against the AntiChrist (Dajjal) and later the tribes of Gog & Magog (Yajuj & Majuj)

Answer (score 5):

If by Yashua (Isha), you mean Prophet 'Issa ﷺ, then the answer is partially no. As Muslims, we believe that Prophet 'Issa ﷺ will descend to rule the entire world under the Islamic *Shari'a* (law), not be the king of Israel.

> #### حَدَّثَنَا عَلِيُّ بْنُ عَبْدِ اللَّهِ حَدَّثَنَا سُفْيَانُ حَدَّثَنَا الزُّهْرِيُّ قَالَ أَخْبَرَنِي سَعِيدُ بْنُ الْمُسَيَّبِ سَمِعَ أَبَا هُرَيْرَةَ ـ رضى الله عنه ـ عَنْ رَسُولِ اللَّهِ ﷺ قَالَ
>
> > #### لاَ تَقُومُ السَّاعَةُ حَتَّى يَنْزِلَ فِيكُمُ ابْنُ مَرْيَمَ حَكَمًا مُقْسِطًا فَيَكْسِرَ الصَّلِيبَ وَيَقْتُلَ الْخِنْزِيرَ وَيَضَعَ الْجِزْيَةَ وَيَفِيضَ الْمَالُ حَتَّى لاَ يَقْبَلَهُ أَحَدٌ
>
> Narrated Abu Huraira: Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said:
>
> > The Hour will not be established until the son of Mary (i.e. Jesus) descends amongst you as a just ruler, he will break the cross, kill the pigs, and abolish the Jizya tax. Money will be in abundance so that nobody will accept it (as charitable gifts).
>
> <sub>— [Sahih al-Bukhari » Book of Oppressions » Hadith 2476](https://www.sunnah.com/bukhari/46/37)</sub>

The same hadith was documented in other books, e.g., [Sahih Muslim » The Book of Faith » Hadith 155 a](https://sunnah.com/muslim:155a).

According to Islam, close to the end of times, Prophet 'Issa ﷺ will descend, not as a prophet or messenger, but as a ruler. He will rule the world with justice and according to the Islamic law. He will break the cross as a sign of denying crucifixion. He will kill pigs as a sign of rejecting the teachings of Paul, and he will abolish the *jizya* as the world will all become Muslims. He will spend forty years on Earth, then die (see [Sunan Abi Dawud » Book of Battles » Hadith 4324](https://www.sunnah.com/abudawud/39/34)).

More information is available from the explanation of this hadith by [Safiur-Rahman Al-Mubarakphuri](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&ID=4256&bk_no=56&flag=1) (Arabic only).

Comment: +1 Might also add that he won't rule "forever" as asked in the question, and will die after a period.

Comment: @Uma — Thank you for noting this. I added the hadith that mentions how long Prophet 'Issa ﷺ will stay on Earth after his descent.